# JW Player 7 HTML5 Primary with Flash Fallback

Tags: html, flash, jwplayer, jwplayer7

Going through the JW Player docmentation I see many examples of Flash rendering with HTML5 fallback but none with HTML5 as the primary playback method.

The reason I ask is because we want to be able to offer our advanced features to users who have HTML5 support while not excluding our clients with older browsers (IE8, IE9)

I have tried the following with no success in IE9:

```js
<!--Course Video, Scripts and Style-->
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/scripts/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/scripts/jwplayer_license.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/scripts/player.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<div id="visualSPPlayer">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer("visualSPPlayer");
    jwplayer().setup({
      playlist: [{
        image: "http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/posters/screen_capture.PNG",
        sources: [{ 
                  file: "http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/Search2013.mp4"
        }, {
           file: "rtmp://s3grslva6x807n.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:Videos/Search2013.mp4"
        }],
         tracks: [{
          file: "http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/captions/Search/Captions.srt", 
            kind: "captions"
        }, {
      file:"http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/chapters/Search/Chapters.vtt",
      kind:"chapters"
      }, { 
      file: "http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/thumbnails/search_thumbnails.vtt", 
        kind: "thumbnails"
      }]
    }],

width: "100%",
aspectratio: "16:9",
primary: "HTML5",
    skin: {
    name: "vapor",
    active: "#E16933",
    inactive: "#E16933",
    background: "#333333"
    }

});
</script>
```

In IE9 it gives Error Loading Media: File could not be played.

In the Flash render you cannot seek using the video timeline.  Is that because the player is relying on native HTML5 seek method?

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is running? By default, html5 should be the rendering method, then Flash as a fallback. Why are you using RTMP as a fallback though? Why not use just the mp4 by itself?

Comment: Hello @EthanJWPlayer the page where this is running is here: http://sharepoint-videos.com/module-1/exploring-new-search-in-sharepoint-2013/  We are no longer using the RTMP delivery for the MP4 video and we are still seeing an error message: File could not be played in IE9.

Comment: That won't work for you, you have to be logged in: http://sharepoint-videos.com/jw-player-page/ is a recreation of the player on the page

Comment: This is running in html5 mode for me as primary. In IE9, since html5 support for video is flaky, we force flash as a primary in this browser.

Comment: Actually, I just checked this in IE9 on Win7, and it plays fine.